# "CFBundleVersion must be a string" from OS X dashboard

Tags: widget, dashboard

While developing my dashboard widget, I looked at the console (system logs) and found that an error message:

```
2009-03-06 22:08:35.244 Widget Installer[3874] CFBundleVersion must be a string
```

The property is marked as type string in Info.plist.  I've tried changing it from a 1.2 number to a series of letters (can't be mistaken for number) and also following apple's versioning guidelines.  No mater, what, I get this error every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Widget Installer parses all the existing widgets to check for older versions.  This message can come from **any widget on your system**, and if you've checked your own, it's probably one of the others.